# Rails generate barcodes from strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, barcode

What is the best way to generate barcodes from strings in a rails app? After displaying the codes in a view I also would like to print them to a pdf file.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When tasked with the same problem, I used [barby](http://toretore.github.com/barby/) to save the barcode as a png, then just loaded that into a pdf (using [prawn](http://prawn.majesticseacreature.com/)). I don't know if it's the *best* way, but it works. :)

Comment: I am having problems using barby, there are no errors but the image is blank... any idea about this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't come across that problem. Maybe try opening a new question specific to that point, or ask on the [barby mailing list](http://groups.google.com/group/ruby-barby/topics).

Comment: The problem seams to be with the png outputer as it works with eps files. Many thanks.

Answer (score 9):

I wanted to write this as a comment to idlefingers' answer, but apparently I don't have enough reputation to do that, so I'll write it here instead.

If you're creating PDFs you can use Barby to render the barcode directly into the PDF file instead of creating an image first:

```
require 'barby/outputter/prawn_outputter'
#aPdf is a Prawn::Document, aBarcode is a Barby::Barcode
aBarcode.annotate_pdf(aPdf, :x => 100, :y => 100)
```

There's also a PdfWriterOutputter.